# All elements in ArrayList change their value unexpectedly

Tags: android, parsing, arraylist, android-asynctask

Here's my class:

```
public class JsoupParser 
{
    ArrayList<CompanyInfo> arr = new ArrayList<CompanyInfo>();

    public static final String SITE = "http://www.example.com/";

    public JsoupParser() {}

    public ArrayList<CompanyInfo> parse(final String link) 
                           throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException
    {

        new RealParser().execute(link).get();

        return arr;
    }

    class RealParser extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void>
    {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... params) 
        {

            Document doc = null;
            String link = params[0];
            try 
            {
                doc = Jsoup.connect(link).get();
            } 
            catch (IOException e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            Elements a = doc.select("a.company_logo");
            Elements img = a.select("img");
            Iterator aIter = a.iterator();
            int i = 0;
            CompanyInfo info = new CompanyInfo();
            while(aIter.hasNext())
            {
                aIter.next();
                info.setCompanyName(a.get(i).attr("title"));
                info.setCompanyListingLink(SITE+ a.get(i).attr("href"));
                info.setCompanyLogoLink(SITE+ img.get(i).attr("src"));
                arr.add(info);
                ++i;
            }
            return null;
        }           
    }
}
```

I'm sure, that the parsing code works fine (tested in Java project).

The problem is, that all the elements of `arr` at the end become the same (all suddenly become equal to the first element inserted to `arr`). I debug and see, that each element differs from another.

Each time the `info` object is different, that means, that I add different elements to `arr` doing this `arr.add(info);`. Debugging in `while` loop everything is OK, but as soon as it quits the `AsyncTask`, the `arr` becomes an ArrayList with multiple of same objects.

How can I solve this? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes because you keep re-using the same `CompanyInfo` object.
You need to move `CompanyInfo info = new CompanyInfo();` within the `while` loop.

Answer (score 2):

put this inside loop

```
CompanyInfo info = new CompanyInfo();
```

like

info = new CompanyInfo();

Answer (score 0):

First, you are adding the same object to your `arr` over and over again. Don't be surprised if that yields your observed result.

Second, you are using the iterator `aIter` in quite an unusual way; looks like you mixed up use of an iterator and loop over an index.